# IBMi/IBMMQ QMQM subsystem stops

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-midrange

I'm still new to MQ and have tried upgraded and downgraded for testing purposes. After I downgraded from 9.2 to MQ 9.1 everything works but I noticed that the qmqm subsystem will be working for hours then will just stop. I checked the QM logs but unable to find anything there.

Please point me to the right direction on where to start investigating

Comment: Can you say a little bit about your downgrade procedure. Did you, for example, take backups of the QMgr data before the upgrade and then restore those after the downgrade?

Comment: You say you checked the QM logs. By that do you mean you looked in /QIBM/UserData/mqm/qmgrs/qmname/errors/AMQERR01.LOG ? Can you show us the messages you saw leading up to the time the QMQM subsystem stops please?

Comment: I followed this direction: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/revert-mq-version-ibm-i I backup the qm data and library. and yes im referring to QIBM/UserData/mqm/qmgrs/qmname/errors/AMQERR01.LOG

Comment: Do you have any applications which are still running (most probably in a get) ?   If so they may not have the fail if quiescing flag set.  It might  have nothing to do with the upgrade and downgrade of MQ.

Comment: So can you update your question to show us the messages you saw in that error log leading up to the shutdown.

Comment: this doesn't seem programming related and is probably more appropriate for https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Joblogs would have errors.  Sounds like a Manager crash.
But even that would not end the subsystem QMQM.

So if subsystem QMQM is ended (which would cause the crash of the Manager), check QHST for the time period leading up to the QMQM subsystem ending. Is someone/thing ENDSBS QMQM *IMMED?  Look for CPF0995 which would have the user profile and backtrack from there.

Unless you mean "subsystem QMQM ended" in the generic sense to describe all the AMQ* Manager jobs crashing and that the actual subsystem is still active.